# How to make sort consider blanks (GNU coreutils)

Tags: sorting, coreutils

How can I make sort consider blanks?

Original file:

```
n  c
n   b
n a
```

What I get with

```
sort file
```

is this:

```
n a
n   b
n  c
```

So how can I come to this order:

```
n   b
n  c
n a
```

Version: sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` depends on locale.  Try:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort file
n   b
n  c
n a
```

Contrast the above with:

```
$ LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" sort file
n a
n   b
n  c
```

#### Documentation

From `man sort`:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the  traditional  sort
>          order that uses native byte values.

Comment: Perfect, thx, forgot that. The -b switch only makes sense this way, too.